# How to get place website and photos for Google Places API nearby search

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I'm using Google Places API to get nearby restaurants, but I've noticed that the results don't include the website address(URL) and exact photo URL.Here is the sample result
 [I searched for resturants near Austrailia, the image shows sample response of "The Star" restaurant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2H0S.png)

If we get the same place "The Star" via google places autocomplete then it do return website URL(http://www.star.com.au/) and photo URL too.
Is there a way to get the website address(URL) and photo included in the results?

This is the call I'm using:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=<lat,lng>&radius=500&type=restaurant&key=<api_key>
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: related issue in the issue tracker: [Issue 9312: Bug: photos object almost always missing from all requests](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9312)

Answer (score 4):

This is because **place search results** contain less detail than **place detail results**.

As the [Search Results documentation for `photos[]`](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchResults) says:

> A Place Search will return at most one photo object. Performing a Place Details request on the place may return up to ten photos.

Similarly, there's no `website` field on search results (and so it is not listed on that documentation page).

You need to make a [Place Details](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) request to get those details:

> A Place Details request returns more comprehensive information about the indicated place

And sure enough, there's a `website` field in the [Place Details Results documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsResults):

> `website` lists the authoritative website for this place, such as a business' homepage.

And that's exactly what I see for the "The Star" in Sydney.  In search results I see 1 photo (just like you see in your screenshot), and no website URL.  Then in the details response for that result I get 10 photos, and the website.